# MS Word: Compare Documents Layout

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, file-compare

I'm using MS Word 2010. I wanted to compare two documents, so I used the built-in compare function, which opened the overly-cluttered layout showing the two versions in two small views, the merged version in a large view and the reviewing pane.

Since I didn't want to merge the documents, only compare them, I closed the merged version view.

Then I ended up seeing only one version (not sure which one) and I can't get back to the normal view, not even when restarting Word, it always opens a single version when I use the compare function.

How can I select which views are shown or at least restore to the default compare layout?

Answer (score 0):

OK I just found my answer.

In the `Review` tab, the `Compare` dropdown menu has a `Show Source Documents` menu, where I can select which documents to show. Strangely enough, there is no option not to show the compared document which is what I had been looking for.